# iOS Simulator Opens then xcode opens, app freezes at start screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, freeze

As the title says the app freezes at the start screen then xcode comes up and displays a green arrow near

```
 self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

**Update**
Here is the full block of code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
MainViewController *aViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]       initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
self.viewController = aViewController;

[aViewController release];

[window addSubview:[navigationController view] ];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
 }
```

Comment: Did you just start a new project? Did you do anything to the project?

Comment: I dont think I did anything to mess it up but that is a possiblity.  It is not a new project.  Any thoughts?

Comment: There are no errors whatsoever listed for my project.

Comment: Did you change anything else in the nibs? Also, are you synthesizing your window and viewController objects in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I didn't change a thing. I took the at symbol off because of the post tagging thing.  
     synthesize window=_window;

     synthesize viewController=_MainViewController;
     synthesize navigationController;
     synthesize managedObjectContext=__managedObjectContext;
     synthesize managedObjectModel=__managedObjectModel;
     synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator=__persistentStoreCoordinator;"

Comment: What is the error it gives you on the line with the green arrow?

Comment: You need to have the "@" symbol on your synthesize, as that is what tells the interpreter to write the getters and setters for you!

Comment: No error!  Thats the strangest part.  The whole app just freezes at the screen.  The only thing that shows up is a green arrow, sorta like a breakpoint but there is no breakpoint there.  Its on the:

     self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

Comment: It also says "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGBART"."

Comment: I took the "@" symbol off for this because it thought i was trying to tag someone

Comment: It is an error there.  If you look to the far right side of the green line, does it say anything?  (Like maybe exc_bad_access or SIGABRT)

Comment: Scroll up above SIGABRT, above the whole part about the call stack at first flow in the debugger console, then post what is written there. SIGABRT usually comes with an enlightening error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as far as I understood, you just want to make your own viewController at startup. Well copy paste the following code I am telling you and give your response.

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

`MainViewController *aViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]       initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];`

`[self.window setRootViewController:aViewController];`

`[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

`return YES;`

`}`

Kindly check once that its `setRootViewController` or `rootViewController` only. I didnt remember exactly. Hope you got the idea.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your application is throwing a runtime exception at that point.  In your case, it is a SIGABRT.  This is an error in your code (not a compile-time check - but rather an exception that occurs when it runs).  I would suspect that it is possible that window doesn't exist in your application (maybe the main nib isn't configured to be setup).

I would replace this line:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view] ];
```

With this line:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Comment: That helped... Sorta... I now get the SIGABRT error on the makeKeyandVisible line.  Any ideas?

Comment: This seems pretty strange... I'd try creating a new project and see if this same error occurs. It seems that something might have messed up the project configuration.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm now getting there SIGABRT error here:
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
Any ideas?  I think its looking like I should just redo the whole application.

Comment: I figured it out.  There were errors in connections with my nib file.  Im still new to this and didn't realize that those errors didnt show up in the main error list.  Thanks for all of your help!